# Future Builder in order to wait a complex widget to be built

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to prebuild a complex page (images, firestore data) in "background" and show a loading screen while waiting for the widget to be fully rendered?

I have `HomePage()` that fetches data from Firestore and load some images
in a slider widget. It takes a while to render images and get data from Firestore. I'd like `main()` to build `HomePage()` in "background" and show a loading screen while waiting.

Comment: check https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await on how to get the `Future` you need to pass to `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @pskink there is no information about entire Widgets as `Future`

Comment: because `Future` brings data only, not `Widget`s, your `Widget` should be a light, dumb data presenter and is going to be build inside the `builder`

Comment: I can't understand your message. Is there a way to show a loading screen while the widget is fully rendered ?

Comment: check this for example: https://brewyourtech.com/complete-guide-to-futurebuilder-in-flutter/

Comment: still a general website talking in general about FutureBuilder, not the specific implementation I'm working on, returning Widgets

Comment: why would you want to return `Widget`s? you should return data, not widgets

Comment: Re-read my question please. I want the complex widget to be fully rendered before appears. So, I want to show loading page until the widget is ready, with all images and data loaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget that does exactly this.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());  
          } else {
            return yourWidget();
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: I know of course... But I don't know how can I implement a `Future` that build an entire widget, not just some piece of data (from Firestore ecc.)

Comment: I added a code snippet above. The snapshot object will contain the results of future.

Comment: I added more explanation of my problem in the question